# Socket emit within the server sided code node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im using MEAN stack, with angularjs frontend, node backend.

Is it possible to make a socket emit call within some functions? im only intrested to emit data to the client side.

Or how pusher server sided is working, could that be done with socket too?

the client request is as follows server sided

```
var bankfactory = require(path.resolve('./modules/articles/server/factory/user_factory.js'));


 app.post('/api/bank', function (req, res) {
bankfactory.bank_inn(req.user._id,amount).then( function (bankresult) {
                res.json(bankresult);
            });
});
```

bankfactory:

```
    exports.bank_inn = bank_inn;


    function bank_inn(playerid,amount) {

if (playerid == 1) {

} else {

    // possible to make a emit call to the client here?
//emit("newevent,datahere)
}

    }
```

is it possible to make a socket emit within there?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own event emitter and emit an event inside the bank_inn function:

```
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

function bank_inn(playerid,amount) {

if (playerid == 1) {

} else {
  myEmitter.emit('myevent', someData);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    myEmitter.on('myevent', function(someData) {
        socket.emit('someEvent', someData);
    });
};
```

Comment: So if I have 80 diff files I need to make that on all of them ?

Comment: no, define myEmitter only once and then emit various events, as many as you need

Comment: I mean the socket on connection ;)

Comment: no, the io.on('connection') also only once.. somewhere ;)

Comment: How do I then call the file contains the socket on and the connections ?

Comment: You are on MEAN, define myEmitter and io() in your app.js (I mean the main express app) and all your other files will see it

Comment: You will find io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { ... in the config/lib/socket.io.js file